# changing tab through combobox and vice versa

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-menu

hi guys anyone can help me? Im new to programming and Im trying to do a small project using tkinter.. basically my problem is how can I make it so when I choose an option from a combobox the tab on the ttk notebook will also be selected and vice versa... thanks in advance

```
 import tkinter as tk
 from tkinter import ttk

 class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.grid()

        frame = Frame(container, self)
        frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

        notebook = Notebook(container, self)
        notebook.grid(column=1, row=0)

 class Frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        combobox = ttk.Combobox(self)
        combobox["values"] = ["a", "b", "c"]
        combobox.grid()


 class Notebook(ttk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        first = ttk.Frame(self)
        second = ttk.Frame(self)
        third = ttk.Frame(self)


        self.add(first, text="a")
        self.add(second, text="b")
        self.add(third, text="c")

 root = Main()
 root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below full code,

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.grid()

        frame = Frame(container, self)
        frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

        notebook = Notebook(container, self)
        notebook.grid(column=1, row=0)

class Frame(ttk.Frame):
    options=["a", "b", "c"]
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        Frame.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self)
        self.combobox["values"] = self.options
        self.combobox.grid()

class Notebook(ttk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        first = ttk.Frame(self)
        second = ttk.Frame(self)
        third = ttk.Frame(self)

        self.add(first, text="a")
        self.add(second, text="b")
        self.add(third, text="c")
        Frame.combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.on_selection)
        self.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>",self.on_tab_selection)
    def on_selection(self,a):
        selected=Frame.combobox.get()
        Frame.options.index(selected)
        self.select(Frame.options.index(selected))
    def on_tab_selection(self,a):
        Frame.combobox.set(Frame.options[self.index("current")])

root = Main()
root.mainloop()
```

Some modifications are made,

```
Frame.combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.on_selection)
self.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>",self.on_tab_selection)
```

above code is used to take the selection events of notebook and combobox

```
def on_selection(self,a):
        selected=Frame.combobox.get()
        Frame.options.index(selected)
        self.select(Frame.options.index(selected))
def on_tab_selection(self,a):
        Frame.combobox.set(Frame.options[self.index("current")])
```

Above two functions are made to handle both events

combobox values are put in a variable list "Options"

Comment: thanks @Arun it worked perfectly!!! I really ahve a lot to learn specially about classes